# In graphics/graphicx, how to show actual pictures despite draft mode

Tags: graphics, draft, trackchanges

For collaboration purposes I am using the `draft` mode in my LaTeX manuscript to show todo-notes, remarks and so on. By switching to final mode all of these additions become unvisible.

However, I'd love to switch on the final mode of the `graphics/x` package to see the actual pictures but `\documentclass` being still in `draft` mode. I get an error about clashing options
when I add

```
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
```

My first guess was that the `\documentclass` already sets the option for the `graphics/x` package. Following doesn't help either

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{graphicx}
\documentclass[twoside,onecolumn,draft]{rsauthor}
```

Comment: Is there a place where `rsauthor.cls` can be examined?

Comment: @egreg: It is freely available from the journal website: Proceedings of the Royal Society A - [rsauthor.cls](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/site/misc/rsauthor.cls)

Comment: Suggestion: Add a tag for "trackchanges" (or mention it in the question so that searches find this better)

Comment: Suggestion: The title would be more readable as: "In graphics/graphicx, how to show actual pictures despite draft mode"

Comment: I am happy with your title suggestion. I've changed it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
\RequirePackage[final]{graphicx}
\documentclass[twoside,onecolumn,draft]{rsauthor}
```

probably works

Also (without doing that) you can flip the draft flag in the preamble (after `\usepackage{graphicx}`) as

```
\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}
```

Comment: no this doesn't help. Thanks for you help anyway.

Comment: odd. what error does it give (I didn't have rsauthor class to test)

Comment: I tried with the `rsauthor` class and both methods work. The second seems preferable.

Comment: @David Carlisle: the second suggestion with `\setkeys` works. Wow, thank you very much. I am always impressed by the fast and perfect help on tex.sx.com.

Comment: I checked again the method with `\RequirePackage`, but still not working. Anyhow, I will accept the answer as given. Possibly in other cases the first suggestions is also of help.

Comment: The RequirePackage technique worked for me but I had to put that line before the \documentclass line.

Comment: `\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}` worked for me, but make sure you don't also have `[draft=false]` or `[final]`in the  \usepackage line.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a conflicting package that loads `graphics`. For example if you load `grffile` because it says so in the `matlab2tikz` documentation, make sure to load it before `graphicx` like so:

```
\usepackage[final]{grffile}    
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
```

Or just leave it, it seems to work ether way. I did not need any other options magic. I only cleaned my header file from packages that load `graphics`.