# Importing Images Problem

Tags: graphics

I need to import an image into my Title page and when I try it only shows a blank box with the image name and extension (College.png). I have set my 'Images' folder in the directory that the .tex file is saved.
My code is as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }

\title{Title}
\date{Date}
\author{Authors}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{College}
```

Any advice would be incredibly helpful, i've only been using LaTeX for a few days.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74898/in-graphics-graphicx-how-to-show-actual-pictures-despite-draft-mode

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/turning-off-and-on-images-in-figures/51894#51894

Comment: also that `\centering`  would be better inside a group or it would affect the whole document. or use `\begin{center}\includegraphics[..]{..}\end{center}`